# How to add a link in Order email template in Magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, order-email, link, attachment

Here i am trying to attach a dynamic link with every order in order email template.
for  eg:

```
<a href="pub/media/000001.pdf">Download Pdf</a>
```

And i have troied

```
<a href="{{media url="'{{var order.increment_id}}'.pdf"}}">Please download PDF</a>


<a href="{{media url="'{{%increment_id}}'.pdf"}}" download>Please download PDF</a>
```

and much more i cant get my exact url with  Order id.
Is there any way where i can attach a link with order id in pub media url.
Small help will be  greatly appreciated.
Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
protected $_storeManager;
private $OrderFactory;


public function __construct(
    .........................................
    .........................................
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $OrderFactory,
    .........................................
    .........................................
) {
    .........................................
    .........................................
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->OrderFactory = $OrderFactory;
    .........................................
    .........................................
}

public function getOrderUrl($order_id)
{
    $order = $this->OrderFactory->create()->load($order_id);
    $link = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
    $link .=  $order->getIncrementId()."pdf";
    return $link;
}
```

in your email template

```
<a href="{{var order_url}}" target="_blank" download>
```

here **order_url** is your email tempate variable name which you pass into email template

Comment: Please be more specifc where should i add this Php file

Comment: add this into your email send code . for more please share your code your can call function by using $this->getOrderUrl($order_id); pass your order id in it.

Comment: I am not using any custom code i am just editing in Config Email Tempalte
Marketing->Email Temp

Comment: you have to pass value into Email Template. without pass value how you can do ?